# Medium sized website: Transition to HTTPS, Apache and reverse proxy

Tags: apache, nginx, https, reverse-proxy

I have a medium sized website called algebra.com. As of today, it is ranked 900th website in US in Quantcast ratings.

At the peak of its usage, during weekday evenings, it serves over 120-150 queries for objects per second. Almost all objects, INCLUDING IMAGES, are dynamically generated.

It has 7.5 million page views per month.

It is server by Apache2 on Ubuntu and is supplemented by Perlbal reverse proxy, which helps reduce the number of apache slots/child processes in use.

I spent an inordinate amount of time working on performance for HTTP and the result is a fairly well functioning website.

Now that the times call for transition to HTTPS (fully justified here, as I have logons and registered users), I want to make sure that I do not end up with a disaster.

I am afraid, however, that I may end up with a performance nightmare, as HTTPS sessions last longer and I am not sure whether a reverse proxy can help as much as it did with HTTP.

Secondly, I want to make sure that I will have enough CPU capacity to handle HTTPS traffic.

Again, this is not a small website with a few hits per second, we are talking 100+ hits per second.

Additionally, I run multiple sites on one server.

For example, can I have a reverse proxy, that supports several virtual domains on one IP (SNI), and translates HTTPS traffic into HTTP, so that I do not have to encrypt twice (once by apache for the proxy, and once by the proxy for the client browser)?

What is the "best practices approach" to have multiple websites, some large, served by a mix of HTTP and HTTPS?

Maybe I can continue running perlbal on port 80, and run nginx on port 443? Can nginx be configured as a reverse proxy for multiple HTTPS sites?

Answer (score 2):

You really need to load test this, and no one can give a definitive answer other than that.

I would offer the following pieces of advice though:

First up Stack overflow is really for programming questions. This question probably belongs on the sister site www.serverfault.com.

Https processing is, IMHO, not an issue for modern hardware unless you are encrypting large volumes of traffic (e.g. video streaming). Especially with proper caching and other performance tuning that I presume you've already done from what you say in your question. However not dealt with a site of your traffic so it could become an issue there.

There will be a small hit to clients as the negotiate the https session on initial connection. This is in the order of a few hundred milliseconds, will only happen on initial connection for each session, is unlikely to be noticed by most people, but it is there.

There are several things you can do to optimise https including choosing fast ciphers, implementing session resumption (two methods for this - and this can get complicated on load balanced sites). [Ssllabs runs an excellent https tester](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) to check your set up, [Mozilla has some great documentation and advice](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS), or you could check out [my own blog post on this](https://www.tunetheweb.com/security/https/).

As to whether you terminate https at your end point (proxy/load balanced) that's very much up to you. Yes there will be a performance hit if you re-encrypt to https again to connect to your actual server. Most proxy servers also allow you to just pass through the https traffic to your main server so you only decrypt once but then you lose the original IP address from your webserver logs which can be useful. It also depends on if you access your web server directly at all? For example at my company we don't go through the load balanced for internal traffic so we do enable https on the web server as well and make the LoadBalancer re-encrypt to connect to that so we can view the site over https.

Other things to be aware of:

You could see an SEO hit during migration. Make sure you redirect all traffic, tell Google Search Console your preferred site (http or https), update your sitemap and all links (or make them relative).

You need to be aware of insecure content issues. All resources (e.g. css, javascript and images) need to be served over https or you will get browsers warnings and refuse to use those resources. HSTS can help with links on your own domain for those [browsers that support HSTS](http://caniuse.com/#search=Hsts), and CSP can also help (either to report on them or to automatically upgrade them - [for browsers that support upgrade insecure requests](http://caniuse.com/#search=upgrade%20insecure)).

Moving to https-only does take a bit of effort but it's once off and after that it makes your site so much easier to manage than trying to maintain two versions of same site. The web is moving to https more and more - and if you have (or are planning to have) logged in areas then you have no choice as you should 100% not use http for this. Google gives a slight ranking boost to https sites (though it's apparently quite small so shouldn't be your main reason to move), and have even talked about actively showing http sites as insecure. Better to be ahead of the curve IMHO and make the move now.

Hope that's useful.